# why this for-loop doesn't run the number of times indicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

i don't know what i am doing wrong here. I think it only run the first command, why it print the list once and it doesn't run the rest of the commands?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
lis = []

def dance(string, lis):
    return {
        'insert': lis.insert(int(string[1]),int(string[2])),
        'print': print(lis),
        'remove': lis.remove(string[1]),
        'append': lis.append(string[1]),
        'sort': lis.sort(),
        'pop': lis.pop(),
        'reverse': lis.reverse(),
    }[string][0]

for i in range(N):
    string=input().split()
    dance(string, lis)
```

the input

```
12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort
print
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function calls all the methods before picking one of them:

```
def dance(string, lis):
    return {
        'insert': lis.insert(int(string[1]),int(string[2])),
        'print': print(lis),
        'remove': lis.remove(string[1]),
        'append': lis.append(string[1]),
        'sort': lis.sort(),
        'pop': lis.pop(),
        'reverse': lis.reverse(),
    }[string][0]
```

You should wrap each one in a lambda and then call the chosen one afterwards:

```
def dance(string, lis):
    return {
        'insert': lambda: lis.insert(int(string[1]),int(string[2])),
        'print': lambda: print(lis),
        'remove': lambda: lis.remove(string[1]),
        'append': lambda: lis.append(string[1]),
        'sort': lambda: lis.sort(),
        'pop': lambda: lis.pop(),
        'reverse': lambda: lis.reverse(),
    }[string[0]]()
```